How to save state for custom cell renderer or cell style as part of grid’s config
I am able to save grid data such as sorting, filtering, pivoting etc using api.getColumnDefs() and then saving the info in my store and then upon reopening adding them back using api.setColumnDefs(), but it seem no way to save custom styles or renderer information such as for example a heatmap.
Is there a way to save cellRenderer or cellStyle or valueFormatter like we can save pivot, filters etc ?
Ps - example :
I am applying heatmap using cellRenderer
columns.map(col => column.colDef.cellRendererSelector = (params) => 
customFunctionHereWhichChecksValueAndReturnsAComponent()

